# How to get the first value of next group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Here is my data sample.

```
df = {"Time": ["2011-01-01 00:00:53","2011-01-01 00:27:47",
                "2011-01-01 00:28:59", "2011-01-01 00:29:01", 
               "2011-01-01 00:29:02"],

      "UPN": ["13", "13", "13", "13", "13"], 

      "Value" : [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
     }

df =  pd.DataFrame(df)
```

[image: Data Sample]

Based on the, `value` column, I have created groups and stored it in `value_grp` column as follows:

```
df["value_grp"] = (df.Value.diff().ne(0).cumsum() | df.Value.diff().eq(0)).cumsum()
```

[image: Grouping]

Now, based on groups, I want to create two new columns: `time_start` and `time_end`. In `time_start`, I want to put the "*first value of the current group*", which I am able to do so by `groupby`. In `time_end`, I want to put *"the first time value of the next group"*.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'UPN'          : df.groupby('value_grp').UPN.first(),
                   'Start_Time'    : df.groupby('value_grp').Time.first(),
                  'Value'   : df.groupby('value_grp').Value.first()
                }) .reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image: Groupby]

Please, guide me how can I get the first value in `time` column of the next group and put it in "end_time" column?

Comment: Use indexed for loops

Comment: @pavi2410 I have tried using loops before, it didnot work.

Comment: Share the code here if you still have it